# Flatten and expand a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, flatten

Objective:

I'd like to convert the following schema:

```
group, id, name
A, 12345, "eeny"
A, 23456, "meeny"
A, 34567, "miney mo"
B, 99999, "foo"
B, 88888, "bar"
B, 77777, "foobar"
```

into:

```
group, id1, name1, id2, name2, id3, name3
A, 12345, "eeny", 23456, "meeny", 34567, "miney mo"
B, 99999, "foo", 88888, "bar", 77777, "foobar"
```

In the context of Python, I'm assuming that can best be accomplished using Pandas groupby() and/or unstack(), but most documentation I've encountered pertains to numerical calculations as opposed to strings.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way.  Add a column representing the count within each group.

```
df['group_num'] = df.groupby('group')['id'].transform(lambda x: range(1, len(x)+1))
```

Then, use the `pivot` function to reshape the data.

```
In [37]: df.pivot(index='group', columns='group_num')
Out[37]: 
              id                name                 
group_num      1      2      3     1      2         3
group                                                
A          12345  23456  34567  eeny  meeny  miney mo
B          99999  88888  77777   foo    bar    foobar
```

This will set the columns as a MultiIndex.  You could flatten down as you show in your desired output like this:

```
In [41]: df = df.pivot(index='group', columns='group_num')    

In [42]: df.columns = [''.join([lvl1, str(lvl2)]) for lvl1, lvl2 in df.columns]

In [43]: df
Out[43]: 
         id1    id2    id3 name1  name2     name3
group                                            
A      12345  23456  34567  eeny  meeny  miney mo
B      99999  88888  77777   foo    bar    foobar
```